# Creating fixture from json file in django

Tags: django, django-fixtures

I'm having problems loading my fixture in Django 2.2

I have a file called data.json in my fixtures folder like this:

```
[{"model": "Headline", "pk": 1, "fields": {"article_link": "https://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/versace-black-code_us_5861fbefe4b0de3a08f600d5", "headline": "former versace store clerk sues over secret 'black code' for minority shoppers", "is_sarcastic": 0}}, {"model": "Headline", "pk": 2, "fields": {"article_link": "https://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/roseanne-revival-review_us_5ab3a497e4b054d118e04365", "headline": "the 'roseanne' revival catches up to our thorny political mood, for better and worse", "is_sarcastic": 0}}, {"model": "Headline", "pk": 3, "fields": {"article_link": "https://local.theonion.com/mom-starting-to-fear-son-s-web-series-closest-thing-she-1819576697", "headline": "mom starting to fear son's web series closest thing she will have to grandchild", "is_sarcastic": 1}}]
```

I have this model:

```
from django.db import models

class Headline(models.Model):
    article_link = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    is_sarcastic = models.IntegerField()
```

I keep getting this error and not sure what is wrong?

```
django.core.serializers.base.DeserializationError:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your fixture should look like this:

```
[
  {
    "model": "myapp.headline",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {
      "article_link": "https://foobar.com",
      "headline": "Test",
      "is_sarcastic": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "model": "myapp.headline",
    "pk": 2,
    "fields": {
      "article_link": "https://foobar.com",
      "headline": "Test",
      "is_sarcastic": 1
    }
  }
]
```

You can have a look here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/initial-data/#providing-data-with-fixtures

Comment: Sorry I changed "model": "Headline" to "model": "sarcasm.headline" (the app is called sarcasm) - still no luck?

Comment: Can you post the full traceback here, please

Comment: Ok thanks for your patience I converted the json to nicely formatted json with an online converter and now I get Could not load sarcasm.Headline(pk=1867): value too long for type character varying(250)
- does not seem to matter how big I set max_length on CharFields

Comment: Your max_length is set to 500 which doesn't exist. Either you use CharField with max_length=255 or TextField without any max_length

Comment: I did change to TextField and did makemigrations but that hasn't helped

Comment: I've temporarily fixed it by just getting rid of long strings - shame, but the actual data isn't important - but it is odd

Comment: That's indeed odd. Thanks for marking it as correct answer